# Is OrganizationServiceProxy Connected?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

What is the best way to tell if an OrganizationServiceProxy has successfully connected to CRM?

I am using GetEnumerator() on AccountSet as this fails if not connected.

```C#
/* Tries to connect to CRM and return false if failure - credentials arguments */
public bool Connect(string username, string password, string uri)
{
    try
    {
        var cred = new ClientCredentials();
        cred.UserName.UserName = username;
        cred.UserName.Password = password;
        service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(uri), null, cred, null);
        service.EnableProxyTypes(); // Allow LINQ early bound queries
        linq = new Context(service);
        /* This is where I need help */
        var e = linq.AccountSet.GetEnumerator(); // this fails if not connected
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;        
}
```

Service and Linq are private fields.

Context is the serviceContextName in crmsvcutil.exe.

I am in the habit of using the name "linq" for the Context object.

There must be a better way.

Comment: What do you want it do to?  It won't attempt to make a connection until you attempt to do something.  How is it supposed to know if it is connected or not?

Comment: I want the method to initialize the service and linq fields, and return false right then if connection failed. Another method uses service.Execute(ExecuteMultipleRequest). Should I leave off checking if the connection has succeeded until I use service.Execute()?

Comment: Rather than calling GetEnumerator(), can you just do a GetFirstOrDefault call to test that it's working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to execute a `WhoAmIRequest`, this because when you connect to CRM you need to provide valid credentials.

If the credentials are correct the `WhoAmIRequest` will return the current user GUID, if are not correct the request will fail.

So your code can be:

```cs
public bool Connect(string username, string password, string uri)
{
    try
    {
        var cred = new ClientCredentials();
        cred.UserName.UserName = username;
        cred.UserName.Password = password;
        service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(uri), null, cred, null);
        WhoAmIRequest request = new WhoAmIRequest();
        WhoAmIResponse response = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(request);
        Guid userId = response.UserId;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: If the password is incorrect a dialogue box pops up asking for credentials. Can this be stopped from happening?